# while converting to data object, Moscow time is one hour behind

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In my application while converting to date object i am always getting one hour behind time . this issue in happening only with moscow time zone.
below is code :

```
    MutableDateTime mdt = new MutableDateTime(time);
    mdt.setSecondOfMinute(0);
    mdt.setMinuteOfDay(0);
    mdt.toDate()
```

in above code mdt.todate() returning 5/30/2021 23:00 instead of 5/31/2021 00:00.

jdk version : "1.8.0_191"

Comment: You should check the TZ/daylight-savings ;)

Comment: TZ is Europe/Moscow only and daylight saving was false.

Comment: Here MutableDateTime time =new MutableDateTime(new Date().getTime());

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Why does "June 6 00:00" after conversion `mdt.toDate()` become "May 31 23:00"?**

Your surprising observation probably comes from an old Joda-Time version with an old time zone database where Europe/Moscow was at offset +04:00 rather than +03:00. It was between 31 October 2010 and 26 October 2014. If Joda-Time “believes” that this is still the case, it sets your `MutableDateTime` to something like `2021-06-01T00:00:00.000+04:00` with offset +04:00 instead of +03:00. This corresponds to `2021-05-31T20:00Z` UTC where the correct point in time would have been `2021-05-31T21:00Z` UTC. In other words, it’s an hour too early. Therefore you get a `Date` that is an hour too early too. Your Java 1.8 “knows” that Moscow is at offset +03:00 these days and therefore prints the time as `Mon May 31 23:00:00 MSK 2021`.

Solutions include:

1. Upgrade to a newer version of Joda-Time that has an up-to-date time zone database.
2. Build your Joda-Time from sources for the version that you are using only with a newer bundled time zone database. This is explained on the Joda-Time home page, see the second link below.

**Original answer**

Your surprising observation probably comes from an old Java version with an old time zone database where Europe/Moscow was at offset +04:00 rather than +03:00. It was between 31 October 2010 and 26 October 2014. I have reproduced your result on my Java 1.7.0_67 and verified that my Java installation “believes” that Moscow is at offset +04:00 and does not use summer time (DST), as was the case in the mentioned period.

Your Joda-Time seems to be new enough to know that Europe/Moscow is at +03:00 so correctly converts your `MutableDateTime` to a `Date` at 00:00 hours on the date in question. Only when you print this `Date`, Java uses its default time zone, still Europe/Moscow, but its own time zone data, and therefore incorrectly prints the time as 01:00 hours instead of 00:00.

Possible solutions include:

1. Upgrade to a newer Java version that has up-to-date time zone data.
2. Fix your current Java installation by upgrading only its time zone database. See *Timezone Updater Tool* in the second link below.

**Setting the time to the start of the day**

Edit: you added:

> Here `MutableDateTime time =new MutableDateTime(new Date().getTime());`

To get a `Date` representing the start of today’s date using Joda-Time:

```
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = LocalDate.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toDate();
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDateObject);
```

Output just now:

> Mon May 31 00:00:00 MSK 2021

Original aside: As an aside, the simpler and safer way to set the time to the start of the day is:

```
    mdt = mdt.toDateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().toMutableDateTime();
```

If you need to keep the same `MutableDateTime` object, instead do:

```
    mdt.setMillis(mdt.toDateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().toInstant());
```

First of all I would be worried that your code may run in a time zone and on a day that in that time zone has a transition at 00:00 so that the first moment of the day is 01:00 or something else. In this case I b believe that your code would throw a surprising exception. Also I find setting individual fields low-level and prefer to set everything in one method call even if it requires further operations to determine the argument to pass to that method.

**Links**

- [Time Zone in Moscow, Russia (Moskva)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow).
- Joda-Time [Updating the time zone data](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).
- [Timezone Updater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html) on Oracle’s web site.

Comment: i think we are confused here, here it is not adding one hour. it is always doing minor one hour. ex: if today start time is "June 6 00:00" after conversion mutabledatetime.todate() is returning me "May 31 23:00". i think some issue with DST.

Comment: Thanks for reverting. You are right, I had not read your question properly at first. I have edited to explain why the time is 1 hour too early (rather than an hour ahead), with a different solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation,any idea which joda version they fixed this issue?

Comment: No, I know nothing about that. I would guess that it would be fixed since version 2.9 from 2016 since Moscow had pretty long been on +03:00 at that time.

Comment: Thank you... after upgrading joda jar to latest version issue got resolved.